# Bootstrap admin template responsive menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get responsive menu working on Metis Admin
http://demo.onokumus.com/metis/

When the screen width is less than 768px, the side menu buttons get smaller which is fine but for the submenus it seems to expand to the right and it's invisible. It's position absolute and I've tried increasing z-index but it still does not show up.

I can see using css inspector that the submenu list is still there and working.

Is there a way to make it displayable?

Comment: Its not working on the online site or its not working in ur own site?

Comment: I've got exact same template on my own site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `overflow:hidden` in your `main.css` line `399`.

Remove this

```
#menu {
/*other styles*/
overflow: hidden; /*remove this line*/
}
```

Now it should work as expected.